# how to access to the parent's siblings value in object like this in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to get colors in headers default is there a way or should i create separate component for headers default style?

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
export default {
    colors:{
        primaryColor: '#4a148c',
        accentColor: '#ff6f00'
    },
    headerDefault:{
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android'? this.colors.primaryColor:'',
            height:100
          },
          headerTintColor:  Platform.OS === 'android'? 'white':this.colors.primaryColor,
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
          headerTitleAlign:'center'
    }
};
```